# JavaScript events/functions triggering not only from button, but from whole page, incremental game

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to make my own little incremental game and have few buttons currently. Buttons are following:

- "Ka-ching" - get money from clicking
- 3 buttons for buying "autoClickers".

My problem is that autoclickers 2 and 3 get bought when enough money when you click anywhere on site, even "Ka-ching" button. I stopped it happening for ka-ching when using `kaching(ev) {ev.stopPropagation();};` but it doesn't work for the others.

My full code: https://jsfiddle.net/veix/sdh94o6m/19/ (interval doesn't work in jsfiddle for some reason, but doesn't matter, it isn't the bug I'm having. Also this jsfiddle doesn't have the `stopPropagation();` in question.

Also part of the problematic parts (I think):

```
//Function for buying Hotdog
function buyHD() {
    if (buyClicker(hotdog.cost, this)) {
        hotdog.clicks += 0.10;
        hotdog.cost *=hotdog.costIncrease;
        hotdog.level++;
        
        var e = document.getElementById("hotdog-level");
        e.innerHTML = "lvl " + hotdog.level;
        
        var e2 = document.getElementById("buyhotdog");
        e2.innerHTML = "Buy for " + hotdog.cost.toFixed(2) + " dollors";
    };
};
```

and

```
//Event Listener for buying Hotdog
var elhd = document.getElementById("buyhotdog");
elhd = addEventListener("click", buyHD, false);
```

How can I stop the events triggering from clicking anywhere? Somehow it doesn't even happen to the first autoClicker button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `addEventListener` on the element that you want to have the click event.

So try `elhd.addEventListener("click", buyHD, false);`

Comment: Got it working already with exactly that same, as other comment said I had typo on the newer eventlisteners.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this a typo .You are writing

```
elhd = addEventListener("click", buyHD, false);
```

but it has to be like this

```
elhd.addEventListener("click", buyHD, false);
```